# Stop Task Manager App History Feature

Tags: windows-10, task-manager

Is there a way to stop Task Manager from logging the App History.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I do not believe so, at least not natively within Windows.

The data there is formed by the Windows subsystems and merely reported on by Task Manager. Task Manager is not very configurable. You can hide row and change the opening priority of the columns, but that is about all.

Comment: Any possible Registry or GPE tweaks?

Comment: None that I know of because Windows data collection runs very deep in the system.